# How to identify moving points together in the time series data

Tags: neural-network, data-mining, k-means, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning

I have a time series of points i.e getting x and y coordinates from some api at some regular intervals and I want to figure out which are the points which are actually moving together on looking their x and y coordinates. Can some one please give me a start point to this problem that whether should I go for KMeans or some supervised learning algorithm.

Comment: k-means will certainly *not* work.

Answer (score 0):

I would try calculating the mutual information.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you exactly want to achieve but i am going to mention some tasks in time series data mining:

- Clustering
- Classification
- Segmentation
- Prediction
- Anomaly Detection
- Motif Discovery

I think that this book: [Time Series Book](http://wiki.epfl.ch/edicpublic/documents/Candidacy%20exam/a12-esling%20time-series%20data%20mining.pdf) will help choose.